# How to load DLL files in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, dll, .net-assembly, gac, azure-data-explorer

I am following [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/api/powershell/powershell) to use Kusto in PowerShell,

When ever I run the installation script ,

```
$packagesRoot = "C:\Myfiles\tools"
dir $packagesRoot\* | Unblock-File
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("$packagesRoot\Kusto.Data.dll")
```

I am getting GAC as False and unable to install the Kusto Dll file as below

[image]

Please help me.

Comment: In case of, you're runnig the script with admin privileges ?

Comment: I'm sorry to hear it, @Dennis. I've removed my previous comment, because the link to my suggestion is now dead, because they seemingly removed the Issues section from their repo, but to recap the gist of the suggestion: Using `Add-Type -LiteralPath "$packagesRoot\Kusto.Data.dll"` rather than `System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("$packagesRoot\Kusto.Data.dll")` is not only more PowerShell-idiomatic, it is also _silent by default_, which avoids the issue at hand.

Comment: I think MS has a new feedback system in place if you'd like to try again :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **There's no error, just unexpected (by you) output**; just use
  `$null = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("$packagesRoot\Kusto.Data.dll")`
  to suppress the unwanted output.
- However, the **PowerShell-idiomatic way to load an assembly** is to use [`Add-Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type), which is silent *by default* (but would report errors if loading failed), unless you use `-PassThru`<sup>[1]</sup>:

```
Add-Type -LiteralPath "$packagesRoot\Kusto.Data.dll"
```

**The output you're seeing is simply how PowerShell's formatting system represents the [`System.Reflection.Assembly`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Reflection.Assembly) object returned from the [`System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom) call - and the fact that such an object was returned implies *success*.**

The `GAC` column reflecting `False` simply tells you that the assembly in the question isn't stored in the GAC.

---

As an aside re the GAC (Global Assembly Cache):

- Neither `System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom()` nor `Add-Type` *install* an assembly [in the GAC], they simply load an assembly *from its current disk location* into the current session for use.
- Generally speaking:

  - Installing assemblies in the GAC is only meant to be performed by Windows Installer - see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/install-assembly-into-gac)
  - [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), the cross-platform successor to Windows PowerShell, is no longer built on .NET Framework, but its cross-platform success, .NET (Core) / .NET 5+, which *doesn't have a GAC anymore*.

---

<sup>[1] `-PassThru` always outputs *type*, not *assembly* information, so that when you combine `-PassThru` with `-Path` / `-LiteralPath`, i.e. when you load an assembly, it is info objects about the *types contained in the assembly* that are output (not an object describing the assembly *itself*, which is what `[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom` does). However, due to a bug as of PowerShell 7.1 relating to *forwarded* types, the latter aren't included, which can result in *no output* altogether - see [GitHub issue #10802](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10802).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

`Import-Module` is complementary with `Add-Type`

- [PowerShell: Import-Module or Add-Type for .NET assemblies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68958466/powershell-import-module-or-add-type-for-net-assemblies)