# Remove event handler in Powershell

Tags: .net, powershell

In Powershell, one may hook an event on a .NET object by calling `add_EventName`, like this:

```
$MyBlock = [System.EventHandler]{Write-Host Hello}
$MyObject.add_Completed($MyBlock)
```

How does one remove that event handler? Or reset the event to the state with no handlers?

This arised from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71356583/cant-use-githttpclient-from-powershell-newtonsoft-json-version-conflict).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
$MyObject.remove_Completed($MyBlock)
```