# PowerShell Core: resolving assembly conflicts

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, .net-assembly

I have found an interesting case which I can't fully understand.

My runtime - PowerShell 7.2.4

I have two PowerShell Core modules: `Net6PowerShellModule` and `NetstandardPowerShellModule`.

---

**Net6PowerShellModule.csproj**:

```cs
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="Net6PowerShellModule.psd1" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Net6PowerShellModule.psd1">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Management.Automation" Version="7.2.4" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**Test-Net6Cmdlet.cs**

```cs
using System.Management.Automation;

namespace Net6PowerShellModule
{
    [Cmdlet("Test", "Net6Cmdlet")]
    public class TestNet6Cmdlet : PSCmdlet
    {
        protected override void ProcessRecord()
        {
            var type = typeof(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection);

            WriteObject("Net6 Cmdlet Run.");
        }
    }
}
```

**Net6PowerShellModule.psd1**

```
@{
    RootModule = 'Net6PowerShellModule.dll'
    ModuleVersion = '0.0.1'
    GUID = '8c1bd929-32bd-44c3-af6b-d9dd261e34f3'
    CmdletsToExport = 'Test-Net6Cmdlet'
}
```

---

**NetstandardPowerShellModule.csproj**:

```cs
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="NetstandardPowerShellModule.psd1" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="NetstandardPowerShellModule.psd1">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Management.Automation" Version="6.1.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**Test-NetstandardCmdlet.cs**

```cs
using System.Management.Automation;

namespace NetstandardPowerShellModule
{
    [Cmdlet("Test", "NetstandardCmdlet")]
    public class TestNetstandardCmdlet : PSCmdlet
    {
        protected override void ProcessRecord()
        {
            var type = typeof(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection);

            WriteObject("Netstandard 2.0 Cmdlet Run.");
        }
    }
}
```

**NetstandardPowerShellModule.psd1**

```
@{
    RootModule = 'NetstandardPowerShellModule.dll'
    ModuleVersion = '0.0.1'
    GUID = 'eef615d0-aecf-4e89-8f4c-53174f8c99d6'
    CmdletsToExport = 'Test-NetstandardCmdlet'
}
```

---

Next, I have two possible use cases for those modules:

1. Import `Net6PowerShellModule`
2. Import `NetstandardPowerShellModule`
3. Run `Test-Net6Cmdlet`
4. Run `Test-NetstandardCmdlet`

Result - everything runs correctly. The only loaded assembly is `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions` version `6.0.0`.

---

1. Import `Net6PowerShellModule`
2. Import `NetstandardPowerShellModule`
3. Run `Test-NetstandardCmdlet`
4. Run `Test-Net6Cmdlet`.

Result - error: `Test-Net6Cmdlet: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. Could not find or load a specific file. (0x80131621)`

---

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68972925/powershell-why-am-i-able-to-load-multiple-versions-of-the-same-net-assembly-in) question, this is not an expected behavior:

> Subsequent attempts to load a different version of the assembly:
> cause a statement-terminating error in Powershell (Core) 7+
> `Assembly with same name is already loaded.`

Why does the first scenario work then?

---

If I add the `RequiredAssemblies = @('Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll')` line in both module manifests, I got an expected behavior: regardless of which module is loaded first, I still got an error: `Assembly with same name is already loaded.`

---

**Update 1**

Articles that I've already looked at:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/dev-cross-plat/resolving-dependency-conflicts
- [PowerShell: why am I able to load multiple versions of the same .NET assembly in one session and also "bypass Dependency hell"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68972925/powershell-why-am-i-able-to-load-multiple-versions-of-the-same-net-assembly-in)
- https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/resolving-powershell-module-assembly-dependency-conflicts/ - this article explains a lot about Assembly Load Contexts, but I still cannot understand the difference between having `RequiredAssemblies` defined in `.psd1` files or using the dependencies in code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**tl;dr**

- When authoring a module, it is best to use a **[module manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/new-modulemanifest) (`.psd1` file) with a `RequiredAssemblies` key to declare dependent (helper) assemblies**, because it **makes loading of such assemblies *predictable*,** because it happens *at the time of module import*.

  - In *Windows PowerShell*, attempts to load a different version of an already-loaded assembly are *quietly ignored* and the newly imported module is made to use the *already-loaded* assembly too, which *may or may not work*.
  - In [*PowerShell (Core)*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) (v6+), attempts to load a different version of an already-loaded assembly are *categorically prevented*.
- If you use *implicit* loading of dependent assemblies, based on .NET's mechanisms, the timing of when these dependencies are loaded isn't guaranteed, and, in PowerShell (Core), you'll bypass the check that prevents attempts to load a different version of an already-loaded assembly - which may or may not work and is only allowed if the later load attempt requests a *lower* version than the one already loaded.
- **Non-trivial workarounds** are needed to reliably **load different versions of a given assembly *side by side***.

---

##### Background information

One of your links, [Resolving PowerShell module assembly dependency conflicts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/dev-cross-plat/resolving-dependency-conflicts?view=powershell-7.2), contains all relevant information, but it's a lengthy read with complex, in-depth information, and it doesn't clarify the way in which *PowerShell (Core) (v6+)* overrides the behavior of the underlying .NET (Core) / .NET 5+ framework.

**Terminology**: For simplicity, I'll use the following terms:

- *Windows PowerShell* is the legacy, ships-with-Windows Windows-only edition of PowerShell whose latest and final version is 5.1.x.

  - It is built on top of *.NET Framework*, the legacy, Windows-only edition of .NET, whose latest and last version is v4.8.x
- *PowerShell Core* (officially now just *PowerShell*) is the modern, cross-platform, install-on-demand PowerShell edition, whose first (but now obsolete) version was v6 and whose current version as of this writing is v7.2.6.

  - It is built on top of *.NET Core* (officially since v5 just *.NET*), the modern, cross-platform, install-on-demand edition of .NET.

**The underlying problem**:

- At the .NET framework / CLR (Common Language Runtime) level, the **fundamental problem is the inability to load different versions of a given assembly side by side into the same *application domain* (.NET Framework) / *ALC* (*assembly-load context*, .NET Core)**: the version that is loaded *first* into a session *quietly wins*, with .NET Core imposing the additional restriction that only attempts to load *lower* versions succeed (see below).
- PowerShell uses only a single application domain / ALC, including for modules, necessitating **workarounds** to enable side-by-side loading of different versions of a (dependent) assembly. The linked article details various workarounds; **a robust, generic, in-process workaround requires PowerShell Core and is limited to *binary* (compiled) modules and is nontrivial**; limited workarounds, some out-of-process, are available for Windows PowerShell and cross-PowerShell-edition code.

**Behavior *without* a workaround:**

- **Windows PowerShell and .NET Framework:**

  - **.NET Framework** *quietly ignores* subsequent attempts to load a different version of an already-loaded assembly, and *makes the caller use the already-loaded version*, *irrespective of whether the requested version is higher or lower* than the already loaded one.

    - Curiously, when the caller uses *reflection* with `typeof` to inspect the assembly and its types it just loaded (whether implicitly or explicitly), the *requested* assembly version is reported - even though it is the *already loaded* assembly and its types that are actually *used*.
  - **Windows PowerShell does *not* overlay this behavior with custom functionality**, although whether or not you use a module manifest (`.psd1` file) with a `RequiredAssemblies` entry can make a difference with respect to *when* dependent assemblies are loaded (see below).
  - **Upshot**:

    - *Attempts* to load a different version of an already-loaded assembly *never fail* and quietly make the caller use the already-loaded version.
    - This *may or may not* work, and you'll only notice at the time the types from the assembly in question are actually *used* (construction of an instance, property access, method calls, ...).

      - Notably, it is likely to *fail* if a later caller attempts to load a *higher* version of an assembly, as it may rely on features that the already-loaded lower version doesn't have, but even the inverse scenario isn't guaranteed to succeed, given that a higher version may have introduced breaking changes.
- **PowerShell Core and .NET Core**:

  - **.NET Core**:

    - *Quietly ignores* subsequent attempts to load a *lower* version of an already-loaded assembly, and *makes the caller use the already-loaded version*
    - *Throws an exception* for attempts to load a *higher* version: `Could not find or load a specific file. (0x80131621)`
    - The rationale appears to be: an already-loaded *higher* version is at least *likely* to be *backward-compatible* with the requested lower version - although, in the absence of semantic versioning for .NET assemblies - this is *not guaranteed*.
    - When no exception occurs, and the caller uses *reflection* with `typeof` to inspect the assembly and its types it just loaded (whether implicitly or explicitly), it *does* see the *actual*, already-loaded assembly version - unlike in .NET Framework.
  - **PowerShell Core *does* overlay this behavior with custom functionality**, unlike Windows PowerShell:

    - It defines a custom dependency handler for the plugin-oriented [`[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom) .NET Core API, which it uses behind the scenes in the following contexts:

      - When loading a module with a module manifest (`.psd1`) that declares dependent assemblies via its `RequiredAssemblies` entry.
      - Calls to [`Add-Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type) with `-Path` / `-LiteralPath`.
      - in `using assembly` statements.
    - This custom dependency resolution handler ***categorically prevents* attempts to load a different version of an already-loaded version**, irrespective of which version number is higher.

      - A statement-terminating `Assembly with same name is already loaded` error occurs (in the case of `using assembly`, loading a script breaks in the parsing stage with `Cannot load assembly '...'`).
  - **Upshot**:

    - In PowerShell Core, attempts to load a different version of an already-loaded assembly *always fail* if you let *PowerShell* make the load attempt.

      - Only if you use .NET Core's *implicit* dependency loading is there a *chance* that the load attempt succeeds, namely if an attempt is made to load a *lower* version later. Implicit dependency loading happens automatically, via the [`[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Reflection.Assembly.Load) .NET API, which is based on supplying a dependent assembly's (location-independent) *full name* and default probing paths for looking for the *file* hosting it, which notably includes the directory of the calling assembly itself.
      - This *may or may not* work, given that versioning of .NET assemblies doesn't use *semantic* versioning, so a higher version of an assembly isn't *guaranteed* to be backward-compatible.
      - Also, the *timing* of implicit loading of dependencies isn't predictable, and usually doesn't happen until the types from the assembly in question are actually *used* (construction of an instance, property access, method calls, ...). Thus, if you rely on your modules to use implicit dependency loading, there is no guaranteed relationship between when a module is imported vs. when actual dependency loading is attempted, so it may fail if a dependency with a *lower* version happens to be loaded *first* in a given session (but, as stated, even if the higher version is loaded first, you may see a later error when the types are actually *used*).

Comment: The workarounds referenced in the linked articles only seem to apply to compiled binary modules. Are there any suggestions or links to suggestions for script modules that can reliably work around PowerShell Core's refusal to quietly ignore version conflicts in dependent assemblies?

Comment: @RyanBolger, I am personally not aware of any. You could try to rely on implicit dependency loading, but that would only ignore a conflict if a _lower_ version than the already-loaded one is targeted. Other than that, the out-of-process workaround may be your only option, but it is both slow and has limitations with respect to type fidelity. I've updated the answer to make it clear that a robust workaround only works with binary modules (and only in PowerShell Core).

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, but thanks all the same.