# Powershell - command was found in the module, but the module could not be loaded

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-keyvault

I am using let's encrypt certificate and azure key vault to automate renewal process using this repo: https://github.com/brent-robinson/posh-acme-azure-example

I have installed the module Az.KeyVault using yaml on azure devops pipeline:

```
# Install the Az PowerShell modules our script will need
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: Install PowerShell Modules (Az.Accounts, Az.KeyVault, Az.Resources, Posh-ACME)
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 'Install-Module Az.Accounts, Az.KeyVault, Az.Resources, Posh-ACME -Force'
    errorActionPreference: 'stop'
    failOnStderr: true
    pwsh: true
```

But, when I run the script, getting the below error:

```
The 'Get-AzKeyVaultCertificate' command was found in the
     | module 'Az.KeyVault', but the module could not be loaded. For
     | more information, run 'Import-Module Az.KeyVault'.
```

When I try to add the import module (`Import-Module -Name Az.KeyVault -Force`) it's giving the below error:

```
Assembly with the same name is already loaded
```

Comment: This means that there's an assembly version conflict, i.e. a different version of an assembly that the `Az.KeyVault` module is trying to load has already been loaded into the session.

Comment: @mklement0 how can I make it right? I didn't mention the version while installing the module so it should always install the latest one. right? What do you mean by assembly version?

Comment: The `Az.KeyVault` probably comes _bundled_ with the assemblies it needs. .NET assemblies are versioned (they have an embedded version number). PowerShell (Core) categorically prevents loading a _different_ version of a given assembly into a session - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72509967/45375). You'll need to find out which assembly/ies, specifically, cause the conflict (I have no simple answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue with the latest version of Posh-ACME module (4.15.0).
Install version 4.14.0 to resolve this.

```
Install-Module -Name Posh-ACME -RequiredVersion 4.14.0 -Force
```

Ref: https://github.com/brent-robinson/posh-acme-azure-example/issues/15#issuecomment-1241850416

Comment: Looks like they fixed it in version 4.15.1
https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Posh-ACME/4.15.1

Answer (score 0):

When you try to install the module in CI/CD pipeline you can specify the user so that it won't conflict with other.

```yaml
#install Az PowerShell Modules with Specific User
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: Install PowerShell Modules (Az.Accounts, Az.KeyVault, Az.Resources, Posh-ACME)
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 'Install-Module Az.Accounts, Az.KeyVault, Az.Resources, Posh-ACME -Force CurrentUser'
```

> The 'Get-AzKeyVaultCertificate' command was found in the
> | module 'Az.KeyVault', but the module could not be loaded. For
> | more information, run 'Import-Module Az.KeyVault'.

> Assembly with the same name is already loaded

The error messages show that ***Az keyVault*** was already installed but not able to load in a pipeline to run task. You can specify the **user**(Current user or all user) to **install the required module** to specific user and **import the required module**.

Comment: Still getting the same error on importing the module. I tried installing modules using `-Scope CurrentUser`

Comment: Give try to uninstall and install again.